# Невыгоден или не выгоден — как правильно?

Tags: орфография, частица-не, единственное-множественное-число

[Из статьи](http://agro-archive.ru/proizvodstvo-produkcii/1016-podgotovka-hryakov-i-matok-k-sluchke-vidy-sluchek.html) о свиноводстве:

> При вольной случке хряк-производитель находится непосредственно в группе свиноматок, что приводит к бессистемному спариванию. При вольной случке норма нагрузки на хряка не более 10-12 свиноматок. С экономической и зоотехнической **точки зрения** этот вид случки **невыгоден**, так как приводит к неэкономному расходованию энергии хряка, не позволяет вести первичный зоотехнический учет, нет возможности проследить происхождение потомства и невозможно оценить животных по качеству потомства.

Мне кажется, что «не выгоден» здесь следует писать раздельно. Так это или нет?

И второй вопрос. Речь идет о двух точках зрения — экономической и зоотехнической. Следовательно, надо писать **точек зрения**?

Заранее благодарен всем ответившим.

Comment: _Spheinx_, объясню свою правку. 1. Вы пишете: _Абзац из статьи..._ Приводите же не полный абзац, а только часть его (причем с изменениями). 2. Оформила отрывок как цитату (**жирным** выделен только спорный текст). 3. Добавила метку. P. S. Отметила бы еще интересный момент: _не более 10-12 свиноматок_ (нужно тире или все-таки дефис; в своей версии Вы поставили тире). P. P. S. Не нравится правка — имеете право откатить.

Comment: Римма Михайлова! Вы все сделали хорошо, я просто еще до сих пор не разобрался, как корректно здесь форматировать текст.

Comment: Что касается дефиса и тире между числительными: дефис ставят, насколько я помню, только между соседними числами и числительными, например, 10-11. А 10–12 надо писать через короткое тире, иначе это может быть понято как "10 или 12". При записи цифрами пробелы не ставятся. Точнее правило не сформулирую, но как-то так...

Comment: М-м... Вот правила Розенталя: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=95#pp95. Как Вы считаете, которое из них нам подходит?

Comment: Параграф 8, пункт 3.
Странно. При записи цифрами тоже ставят пробел? Но у кого-то из довольно авторитетных авторов я читал об обратном. У кого — не помню.
Еще один любопытный момент. Использованы длинные тире вместо коротких. Но это допустимо. Раньше короткие тире в русском языке использовали очень редко. Сие — тлетворное влияние Запада.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Здесь лучше подходит **слитное написание**:

*С экономической и зоотехнической точки зрения этот вид случки **невЫгоден,** так как приводит к неэкономному расходованию энергии хрЯка*…

По семантике формы практически не различаются, но **по структуре** предложения слитная форма **более корректна.**

Дело в том,  при раздельном написании НЕ  это слово должно быть **логически выделено,** а в распространенном предложении это сделать сложно (мы практически сразу переходим к указанию причины).

Кроме того, **при отсутствии семантического отличия** слитная форма письма является **предпочтительной,** что видно из Нацкорпуса (слитное написание — 43 примера, раздельное написание — 8 примеров).

**ПРИМЕЧАНИЕ.** Различие в семантике учитывается **при градации** признака: ***дом небольшой*** (маленький) и ***дом не большой*** (средний).  В этом случае форма письма соответствует разной оценке величины, и тогда **подбор подходящего синонима** действительно становится актуальным. При одинаковой же семантике  замена синонимом практически **ничего не дает** для решения задачи.

2. *С экономической и зоотехнической **точки зрения**…*

Правило Розенталя:  [http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/65.htm#з_04](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/65.htm#%D0%B7_04)

Имя существительное, которому предшествует **два или несколько определений,** указывающих на разновидности предметов, ставится в форме **единственного числа:**

(4)  если перечисляемые разновидности предметов или явлений **внутренне связаны, например, в сочетаниях терминологического характера**: ср.:
оперное и балетное искусство; промышленный и аграрный переворот; в старославянском и древнерусском книжном языке; глаголы совершенного и несовершенного вида. [http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/65.htm#з_04](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/65.htm#%D0%B7_04)

**Дополнение**

Художественный  иронический диалог на тему **«По семантике формы практически не различаются»**

– «Невыгоден» – является невыгодным, «не  выгоден» – не является выгодным.  Понял, Иван?

– Да, понял. А в чем разница-то?

Answer (score 2):

В данном случае «невыгоден» пишется слитно.

Это краткое прилагательное.

> **Не с краткими прилагательными пиши, как с полными**: дорога нелегка
> (трудна, тяжела) = дорога нелёгкая (трудная, тяжёлая).
>
> Пиши не с краткими прилагательными раздельно, если полная форма не
> употребительна: не рад, не должен, не горазд, не намерен.
>
> [[russkiy-na-5.ru](http://russkiy-na-5.ru/rules/111)]

Если рассмотреть полное прилагательное «невыгодный».

> Слитно пишется не с именами прилагательными, которые не лишаются при
> этом утвердительного смысла, а лишь приобретают противоположное
> значение. Такие прилагательные имеют синонимы без не:
>
> ```
> невеселый (грустный), неглубокий (мелкий), недружелюбный (враждебный), неплохой (хороший); ср.: На берегу их провожали две фигуры небольших (маленьких) людей: Федератовна и Умрищев (Плат.); Матвей очень дивился тому, что у Димы оказался такой непостоянный (изменчивый) характер (Кор.); Утро оказалось неудачное (Наб.); Еще фараоны знали секрет повиновения: чтобы держать народ в страхе, карай не виновных, карай невинных (из газ.).
> ```
>
> [[gramma.ru](http://gramma.ru/RUS/?id=4.53)]

Это высказывание является утвердительным — утверждается отсутствие выгоды, а не отрицается её наличие.

В данном контексте можно заменит на антоним «убыточный».

*«С экономической и зоотехнической точки зрения этот вид случки **убыточен**, так как приводит к неэкономному расходованию энергии хряка…»*

---

Правильно: *«…с экономической и зоотехнической **точек** зрения…»*

Потому что подчёркивается наличие двух разных точек зрения.

> 2. Имя существительное ставится в форме множественного числа:
>
> 1. если подчеркивается наличие нескольких предметов, например:
>
>    ```
>    московский и горьковский автозаводы; биологический и химический методы; академическое и массовое издания произведений классиков, широкоэкранный и обычный варианты фильма; марганцевая и хромовая руды; соляная и серная кислоты; кузнечно-прессовый и сборочный цехи; золотая и серебряная медали; гидроэнергетическая и оросительная системы; токарный и фрезерный станки, ходовая и боевая рубки крейсера; овечья и телячья шкуры, разрыв между первым и последним гонщиками, встречи с болгарской и польской футбольными командами; участники гражданской и Великой Отечественной войн.
>    ```
>
> [[Розенталь](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/65.htm)]

Сравните:

*Даже не буду пытаться изображать беспристрастность: к чешской марке у меня самое трепетное отношение и с клиентской, и с профессиональной **точек** зрения…*
[spb.ru](https://dp73.spb.ru/news-60018-shkode-125-maloizvestnye-fakty-i-zabytye-mashiny.html)

*Описать феномен стволовой клетки с научной и обывательской **точек** зрения.*
[[ppt4web.ru](https://ppt4web.ru/biologija/stvolovye-kletki-i-vyrashhivanie-organov-i-tkanejj.html)]

*Оbuhova L.F. (2003), Проблема старения с биологической и психологической **точек** зрения (Problems of eldering from biological and psychological point of view), “Психологическая наука и образование” no. 3*
[[jecs.pl](https://jecs.pl/index.php/jecs/article/view/799/658)]

Comment: Я бы предложила написать "как с экономической, так и с зоотехнической точки зрения..."  "Имя существительное ставится в форме единственного числа... 3.Если между определениями стоят противительные, разделительные или сопоставительные союзы, например: не норвежский, а голландский конькобежец; латинский или готический шрифт; то широкая, то узкая дорога; как в прошлом, так и в нынешнем году; если не в соседнем, то в более отдаленном регионе."

Comment: Спасибо за мысль, но получается как-то казенно и длинновато.

Comment: @Nadezhda Спасибо за комментарий. Вы имеете в виду, написать так, чтоб уйти от спорного вопроса: единственное или множественное число? На мой взгляд, если так как в тексте сейчас, то должно быть множественное число, потому что есть точка зрения науки экономика и есть точка зрения зоотехники. Точки зрения две (двух разных наук). Невыгоден как с одной точки зрения, так и с другой. Подчёркивается, что есть две точки зрения и с обоих невыгоден.

Comment: @Spheinx Насчёт «казённо и длинновато» — это не детская книжка. Давайте будем говорить по сути вопроса. Ответ может быть правильным или неправильным, а не «казённым» или «длинноватым». С чем вы не согласны по сути? Вы в своём вопросе пишете: _«Речь идет о двух точках зрения — экономической и зоотехнической. Следовательно, надо писать точек зрения?»_. И это действительно так. Но при этом вы принимаете ответ с написанием в единственном числе.